# PHP: read contents from a file and echo the name of the folder that file belongs to

Tags: php

There are a directory full of random folders and inside all those folders is name.txt

Example: abcd/name.txt, 1234/name.txt, xyz/name.txt

```
<?php $users_input = "Jonathan"; ?>
```

I want to check if $users_input is equal to the contents of any random folder's name.txt and echo **THAT** folder's name.

Like (if $users_input is equal to contents of 1234/name.text) {echo folder's name which is *1234*}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include things that you tried and possible error messages in your post.

Comment: You can use `glob("*/name.txt")` to get a list of all of them. Loop through the files, call `file_get_contents`, and compare `$users_input` with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to achieve this, as follows:

```
$users_input = 'Jonathan';
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/target/path'));

foreach ($iterator as $file)
{
    if ($file->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    $path = $file->getPathname();
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);

    if (strcmp($contents,$users_input)) {
        echo $path.'<br\>';
    }
}
```

You may want to include an additional check on the file name if the folders can contain other files with a different name and or extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the solution will look like based on Barmar's suggestion:

```
<?php
$users_input = "Jonathan";
$file_arr = glob("*/name.txt");
foreach ($file_arr as $path) {
  $content = file_get_contents($path);
  if (trim($content) === $users_input) {
    echo "dirname: " . dirname($path) . "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Concluded with

```
$users_input = "Jonathan";

$directory = glob("*");

foreach ($directory as $path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $myfile = fopen($path."/name.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        if (fread($myfile,filesize($path."/name.txt")) == $users_input) {echo $users_input . " is in " . $path;}
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```